# Homebrew: clisp no bottle available

Tags: homebrew, common-lisp, clisp

I'm completely new to Home Brew and am trying to install Common Lisp

https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/clisp

When I run `brew install clisp`

I get:

```
Error: clisp: no bottle available!
You can try to install from source with:
  brew install --build-from-source clisp
```

As far as I can ascertain, I've installed Home-brew correctly.  For example when I type `brew doctor` I get `Your system is ready to brew.`

I've also tried building from source with no success.

What am I doing wrong?  I'm running Big Sur on M1.  Thanks in advance.

Brew Config:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 3.2.10
ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew
HEAD: ab2118a402a44451b1d7559167b6956dc47cc19a
Last commit: 2 days ago
Core tap ORIGIN: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core
Core tap HEAD: a9432939d7dc6c8c792dd5360e3e0aa096584a6c
Core tap last commit: 2 hours ago
Core tap branch: master
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_CASK_OPTS: []
HOMEBREW_MAKE_JOBS: 8
Homebrew Ruby: 2.6.3 => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
CPU: octa-core 64-bit arm_firestorm_icestorm
Clang: 12.0.5 build 1205
Git: 2.30.1 => /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git
Curl: 7.64.1 => /usr/bin/curl
macOS: 11.5.2-arm64
CLT: 12.5.0.0.1.1617976050
Xcode: 12.5.1
Rosetta 2: false
```

Comment: Try installing the SBCL implementation. It is more developed, it was ported to more architectures, and it is the fastest one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an ARM Mac and the `clisp` doesn't support built as native arm64 package. You need to install a Rosetta Homebrew as well.

Quote from [Apple Silicon support in Homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/10152)

> We now have a majority of our formulas bottled for Apple Silicon: 70%. However, not all software is ready for ARM processors on macOS, and since we ship what upstream releases, there will be some formulas that take a long time to be fixed, have a new release… and some which will never support ARM.
>
> Our level of support is this: **Homebrew strives to ship ARM bottles for software that does support ARM**. We can't fix every software that's out there, and we won't accept feature requests like “formula Z does not support ARM can you fix it”. The most useful way you can help that software work on ARM is to open a bug report with the software developers.

That's one of the reason why Homebrew chooses `/opt/homebrew` as the homebrew prefix for M1 Mac, but not the old `/usr/local`. Users may need Apple Silicon Homebrew (installed in `/opt/homebrew`), Rosetta2 Homebrew (`/usr/local`) coexist.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in the [bottle block](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/clisp.rb#L25-L31), there is no bottle in there (which means it is not supported in homebrew yet).